# Error Message On Start Up

Tags: windows-7, window, touchsmart

Up on Start Up I get the following Message:

> C:\Users\CarolM\AppData\LocalConduit\BackgroundContainer\BackgroundContainer.dll
>   Specific module could not be found

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: I believe solution to you problem has been already posted on [Answers Microsoft site](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_scanner-protect_scanning/run-dll-error-messagebackground-containerdll/49612202-667e-4a71-8e9a-d02161d8bc19)

Answer (score 0):

Copied relevant part of the comment:

```
A RunDLL "Error loading... message usually occurs when the .dll file 
that was set to run at startup in the registry or as a scheduled task
has been deleted.

Windows is trying to load this file(s) but cannot locate it since the
file was mostly likely removed during an anti-virus or anti-malware
scan. However, an associated orphaned registry entry still remains
and is telling Windows to load the file when you boot. 

Since the file no longer exists, Windows will display an error message. 
You need to remove this registry entry so Windows stops searching for
the file when it loads.
```

To resolvbe this, use software like [auroruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902). I guiess ccleaner will also solve it.